# refreshApex not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, refreshapex

I have a custom lwc that needs to refreshApex once a certain button is clicked but it's not working for me. It also doesn't get recalled when I change some of its parameters:

LWC:

```
wiredZC;
@wire (getZipCodesByCenter, { centerID : '$center', CPfilter : '$cp_filter' }) zipcodeW (response){
    this.wiredZC = response;
    console.log('****center', this.center, this.cp_filter);
    if(response.data) this.zipcodes = response.data;
    else if(response.error) this.showToast({ message : response.error.body || response.error.body?.message, variant : 'error' });
}
////
handleRefresh(){
    refreshApex(this.wiredZC); 
    
}
```

`handleRefresh` is a function I've checked it's being called but for some reason, if I change the center or I call this function is not working.

Apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
public static List<Zip_Code__c> getZipCodesByCenter(String centerID, String CPfilter){
    String query;
    List<Zip_Code__c> result = new List<Zip_Code__c>();

    //Search zipcodes by center and, if filled, filter by CP
    if(String.isBlank(centerID)){ return result; }
    try{
        query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Zip_Code__c WHERE Center__c = :centerID';
        if(!String.isBlank(CPfilter)){ query += ' AND Name LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(CPfilter) + '%\''; }
        result = Database.query(query);
    }
    catch(Exception exc){
        throw new AuraHandledException(exc.getMessage());
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing/doing wrong?

Regards,

Comment: "not working" isn't a helpful description. Have you checked the browser's Developer Console (F12) for errors on the Console? Have you checked out the Network tab to see if your Apex is being called? Have you checked Salesforce's Developer Console (⚙️>Developer Console) to see if your Apex is throwing an error? I don't see any obvious reasons why this wouldn't work. Doing some debugging should help you help us, or at least make it obvious why it's not working.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm not seing the console.log each time I tried firing my method again and also not seeing any error being thrown or my method being called in the Developer Console